# express cookie-session gone after browser quit

Tags: session, cookies, express

I'm using express `cookie-parser` and `cookie-session` to manage sessions in my Node app. The code is more or less this:

```
app.use(require('cookie-parser')(process.env.COOKIE_SECRET));

app.use(require('cookie-session')({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  cookie: {
    path    : '/',
    signed  : true,
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge  : null
  }
});
```

As far as I understand it, this session should not expire until the user logs out or clears their cookies, however, the session appears to only last until the user quits their browser. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching to using Mozilla's [client-sessions](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions), and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add in `req.session.cookie.expires = false;` when you render the clients page.